# Adding 2 new columns to my table I get "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql

I have just realized that I need to add more columns into my table. I have been running my database live for about a year, and wanted to add a few date fields (logged in date).

I exported the schema and data. I edited the exported sql file to add the following lines in my table definition

`lastLoginDate` date NULL,
  `fromAndroid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' NULL,

But I get the above error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

Is there a way to add rows, without modifying each line in the data ? I mean I can go thru each line one by one and add `null, null`, but thats a crude way to doing it.

I have checked out the other answers, but none of them have my scenario. I actually **dont match the value count**.

Edit : I am not doing a insert, I am doing a import  `mysql -u username -ppassword dbname < dbfile.sql`

Comment: Show the insert statement.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to execute `ALTER TABLE` statement to add more columns

Comment: just do an alter table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD COLUMN (lastLoginDate date NULL, fromAndroid tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' NULL)
```

You may save the above script into a file, for example, modify_table.sql and then execute this following:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword dbname < modify_table.sql
```